# Open url contents on click of a tab in same tab pane

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in web development. I am working on a small project which needs to open a url(something like http://192.168.1.107:8080) content on click of a tab, in the same tab pane. The mentioned url is a client, which displays some runtime data(eg: temperature) continuously.

I could find some code snippets on creating tabs, but I'm keen to get this specific requirement working.

I would appreciate any code snippets, links or information on displaying a url data in same tab pane please.

sorry for vague question, but this is how I could put it in the words.

This is the sample code I have:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="temp1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#temp1" role="tab" aria-controls="temp1" aria-selected="true">Temperature 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="temp2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#temp2" role="tab" aria-controls="temp2" aria-selected="false">Temperature 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="temp3-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#temp3" role="tab" aria-controls="temp3" aria-selected="false">Temperature 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="temp1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="temp1-tab">
        Display temp1 <br />
        <iframe src="http://192.168.1.107:5000/" title="Temp 2"></iframe> 
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="temp2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="temp2-tab">
        Display Temp2
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="temp3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="temp3-tab">
        Display Temp3
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$('.tab-link').on('click', function(event) {
    // Prevent url change
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // `this` is the clicked <a> tag
    $('[data-toggle="tab"][href="' + this.hash + '"]').trigger('click');
})
</script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

thanks

Comment: Please share the code you have so far and where you're getting stuck. Your requirements don't make sense if you're talking about browser tabs, and the way to add/navigate to tabs inside the current page depends heavily on how you've created them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open a URLinside your website, you can use an iframe to do so. Sample example:

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.1.107:8080/" title="Tab 2"></iframe>
```